# Does the uncertainty $\Delta \hat a$ of the annihilation operator of the harmonic oscillator remain constant over time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm supposed to prove that the uncertainty of the annihilation operator of the harmonic oscillator, given by

$$\Delta \hat a=\sqrt{\langle\hat{a}^{2}\rangle-\langle\hat{a}\rangle^{2}} \tag1$$

doesn't change over time.

---

**My attempt at a solution**

What I have tried is to calculate the derivatives of $\langle\hat{a}^{2}\rangle$ and $\langle\hat{a}\rangle^2$ to compute the derivative of the uncertainty $\Delta \hat a$:

$$\frac{d(\Delta \hat a)^{2}}{d t}=\frac{d\langle\hat{a}^{2}\rangle}{d t}-\frac{d\langle\hat{a}\rangle^{2}}{d t} \tag2$$

For that, I have used the equation for the time-evolution of quantum-operators:

$$\frac{d}{d t}\langle A\rangle=\frac{1}{i \hbar}\langle[A, H]\rangle+\left\langle\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}\right\rangle \tag3$$

After doing some calculations, the result I have obtained is the following:

$$\frac{d\langle\hat{a}^{2}\rangle}{d t}=-i2\omega \langle\hat{a}^{2}\rangle$$

$$\frac{d\langle\hat{a}\rangle}{d t}=-i\omega \langle\hat{a}\rangle \rightarrow \frac{d\langle\hat{a}\rangle^2}{d t}=-i2\omega \langle\hat{a}\rangle^2$$

So, finally, I get:

$$\frac{d(\Delta a)^{2}}{d t}=-2i\omega (\langle\hat{a}^2\rangle-\langle\hat{a}\rangle^2)=-2i\omega(\Delta \hat a)^2$$

I don't know if it can be argued in any way that the result should be zero... If not, I've gone over the calculations several times and I think the result is correct.

Comment: $\hat{a}$ Is not an observable since it is not selfadjoint and it does not admit a spectral decomposition which permits the standard interpretation of the formalism. The question does not make much sense in my view.

Comment: Valter Moretti I think he is just talking about mathematical steps.

Comment: @Valter Moretti Then, does $(3)$ only work for self-adjoint operators? I wasn't sure about that

Comment: The point is that $\psi| A \psi\rangle$ is an expectation value only if there is a spectral decomposition of $A$ so that $\langle \psi| A \psi\rangle = \int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda d\mu_\psi(\lambda)$ where $\mu_\psi$ is a probability measure (assuming $||\psi||^2 =1$) and we have a true expectation value. $\hat{a}$ does not admit spectral decomposition because it is not normal.

Comment: However if one forces the formalism and declares that $\langle \psi| X \psi \rangle$ is an expectation value for every operator $X$ (false)...

Comment: Along with this herroneous intepretation I think that your computations are correct and $\Delta \hat{a}$ is **not** constant in time.

Comment: A more direct approach is based on $\hat{a}(t) :=  U_t^\dagger \hat{a} U_t = e^{-i\omega t}\hat{a} $ which implies $\Delta \hat{a}(t)^2 = e^{-2i\omega t}\Delta \hat{a}(0)^2$.

Comment: Further to @ValterMoretti ‘s point, because $\hat a$ is NOT an observable there is no guarantee (for instance) that your $(\Delta a)^2$ is actually positive.